# A word for "a combination of numbers that only involves addition and subtraction"

Tags: single-word-requests, numbers

An ***arithmetic combination*** of numbers is any combination that involves taking a sum, difference, product, or quotient

I'm wondering if there is a word that satisfies:

> A(n) ________ *combination* of numbers is any combination that involves taking a sum or difference.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is an exact word for this, and if there is, it's probably well known only to mathematicians. It's possible that [factor](https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/factor.html) is what you're looking for, but consider asking this on [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I thought 'binary combination' was applied to any process involving a dual input. It could be as simple as 'output the larger' or 'output the first listed'. Or 'output the mean'.

Comment: @MikeHarris "Factor" only refers to multiplication, not addition or subtraction.

Comment: @Hank One multiplies factors together, but the individual factors may contain sums/differences, or they can be atomic values. See the examples at the bottom of the page that I linked. (But _factor_ still isn't as restrictive as what OP is looking for, I think.)

Comment: @MikeHarris  read it as looking for a word to describe the "2 + 3" combination in "2 + 3 = 6". I saw what you linked but just because that "factor" uses addition doesn't mean all are factors. Those are factors because they are multiplied together. If we look at "10 * cow = 10cow", cow is a factor, but not all cows can be called factors. Using **factor** for describe what the OP wants is no more accurate than using **number** to describe it, no offense.

Comment: @Hank correct, good point.

Comment: To the OP, please add to the post the research you performed? Also what did you find from your research?

Comment: There is the standard term "linear combination". One speaks of a linear combination of vectors or of functions or of matrices or of variables. In the expression 4x + 3y, as the values of x and y vary, the 4 and the 3 remain fixed, and one calls this a linear combination of x and y, and the numbers 4 and 3 are called the coefficients in the linear combination. If it had say 4x - 3y, then it would be the same as 4x + (-3y) and it would be a linear combination whose coefficients are 4 and -3.

Comment: Things that get multiplied are called factors, thus in the expression 4*3 = 12 (where the asterisk denotes multiplication) the numbers 4 and 3 are factors and 12 is the product. A product is a number obtained by multiplying, just as a sum is a number obtained by adding. In the expression a+b-c+d, the numbers a, b, c, and d are called terms, or sometimes one may view this as a+b+(-c)+d and say that a, b, -c, and d are the terms. But I have also seen the word "terms" used to refer to factors, i.e. things that get multiplied, when the number of things being multiplied is large.

Comment: Well,  again in mathematics,  if you have a set with a single (commutative) operation,  it's called an  Abelian Group.  If you add a second (commutative) operation, it's called a Ring.

Comment: @Hank My research came up with arithmetic combination.  This wasn't restrictive enough, so I brought the question here.

Comment: Comments are temporary and are not always read. Please add to the post not the comments.

Comment: The comment is just paraphrasing the post's first sentence. I only repeated it here to show you that the post already answers your two questions. Therefore, there is nothing to add to the post.

Answer (score 2):

For your exact wording, "additive (combination)" fits most closely. This said, however, a "sum" would likely best describe what you are referring to, as differences are simply additions of negative terms.

Comment: Yeah, it's a **sum**.

Comment: Why not call it a "difference", since sums are simply subtractions of positive numbers?

Comment: It would be just as correct, but I don't think it sounds as good.

Comment: @Clare because the fundamental operation is adding;  subtraction is the reverse operation.

Comment: @Clare - Plus, addition is commutative, subtraction isn't.

Comment: I like this answer, but I finally realized why it didn't sit perfectly with me. What if I have a set of only positive numbers, and I want to take some additive/subtractive combination of them? Then, what would be a good way to structure this phrase? "A sum of numbers (some of which are replaced with negations of themselves)" That sounds too wordy.